# clear the inpute react ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I wrote the following code and the problem I have is that when I click on the buttons, the value of my counter changes, but the first number I entered remains in the input and does not change.
So how can I clear the input value after I enter a number?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const App: React.FC = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0)

    const increaseHandler = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setCount(count + 1)
    }

    const decreaseHandler = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setCount(count - 1)
    }

    const resetHandler = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setCount(0)
    }

    const changeInputHandler = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setCount(+event.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <form>
            <div>
                {count}
            </div>
            <section style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "row"}}>
                <button onClick={increaseHandler}>increase</button>
                <button onClick={resetHandler}>reset</button>
                <button onClick={decreaseHandler}>decrease</button>
            </section>
            <input value={count} onChange={changeInputHandler}/>
        </form>
    )
}
export default App
```

Comment: There is no `value` prop on the `input` so it's uncontrolled.

Comment: try giving it a value  `<input value={count} onChange={changeInputHandler}/>`

Comment: ok I wrote it but it didnt solve my problem.